# Запись html в Sqllite3 из под PyQt5

Tags: python, база-данных, pyqt5, sqlite, gui

При попытке записать в бд **`html`** из `QTextBrowser.toHtml()` происходит ошибка `sqlite3.OperationalError`.

В интернете нарыл только метод с использованием `QString`, но в *PyQt5* его нет. [Ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27758276/13230196).

Минимально воспроизводимый пример:

```
import sqlite3

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import QTextCharFormat, QFont

conn = sqlite3.connect("testdb.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS texts
                  (content TEXT)
               """)
conn.commit()


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.textbrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser()
        self.textbrowser.setFixedSize(300, 300)
        self.textbrowser.setReadOnly(False)

        self.make_bold_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('set bold')
        self.make_bold_button.clicked.connect(self.set_bold_foo)

        self.save_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('save')
        self.save_button.clicked.connect(self.save_text_foo)
        box.addWidget(self.textbrowser)
        box.addWidget(self.make_bold_button)
        box.addWidget(self.save_button)

        self.setLayout(box)

    def set_bold_foo(self):
        cursor = self.textbrowser.textCursor()
        text_char_format = QTextCharFormat()
        text_char_format.setFontWeight(QFont.Bold)
        cursor.mergeCharFormat(text_char_format)

    def save_text_foo(self):
        cursor.execute(f"""INSERT INTO texts
                      VALUES ('{self.textbrowser.toHtml()}')"""
                       )
        conn.commit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Надеюсь вам поможет данная ссылка: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37754138/how-to-render-html-with-pyqt5s-qwebengineview

Comment: А также вот эта: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56604646/how-do-i-load-display-an-html-file-into-my-qtextbrowser-widget

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А вы не думали что будет когда в `html` встретится символ закрывающей кавычки?

**`У вас прямо классический пример для демонстрации атак с использованием sql инъекции.`**

Используйте QSqlQuery с передачей параметров через bindValue. В этом случае sql драйвер сам позаботится
https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/overviews/sql-sqlstatements.html

В вашем случае соответственно

```
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery

...
db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
db.setDatabaseName('testdb.db')
db.open()

...

query = QSqlQuery()
query.prepare("INSERT INTO texts VALUES (:content)")
query.bindValue(":content", self.textbrowser.toHtml())
query.exec()
```

Answer (score 1):

Дополнение к соседнему ответу, для `sqlite3` из python binding-параметры передавайте через `?`:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO texts VALUES (?)", [self.textbrowser.toHtml()])
conn.commit()
```